# Definite article in "Police were able to find out where the father lived from _THE_ information the child provided"

Tags: articles

From the BBC article "[Bravery of France 'heart attack boy' is praised](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-35273479)":

> Police and the emergency services were able to find out where Kevin Djene's father lived from *information* the child provided.

Can we put in the definite article before "information"?

> Police and the emergency services were able to find out where Kevin Djene's father lived from **the** *information* the child provided.

After all, the noun is postmodified by "the child provided", and from the context we already know what that information was about.

Comment: *Jean Francois Pinot told the BBC he saw the child in his pyjamas riding his cycle late at night on a rural road.* I'm trying to figure out what the farmer was doing in the boy's pyjamas, and who's riding whose bike. I guess the French know, since they have a law about it. Seriously, though, the use of pronouns and referents in this article is slapdash, as is the title.

Comment: To my mind, "from information" says to me "from some of the information", whereas "from the information", means from all of the information (more likely to be a single fact). That's how it occurs to me when reading it and not thinking too deeply about it (UK native speaker).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=from%20information%20provided%20by%2Cfrom%20the%20information%20provided%20by&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfrom%20information%20provided%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfrom%20the%20information%20provided%20by%3B%2Cc0), *from information provided by* is over twice as common as *from **the** information provided by*. Personally, I think that preference would be even stronger if I could generate a chart comparing *from [the] information provided by **the***, because it's stylistically a bit ugly to include the first [optional] article when it's closely followed by another [probably, *non-optional*] article.

[image]

Note that [***information*** is a "non-count" noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117552/why-does-information-not-have-a-plural-form). If we consider alternative phrasing with a countable noun such as ***statement***, we're contrasting...

> 1a: *He was identified using **the information** the boy gave*
>    1b: *He was identified using **information** the boy gave*
>    2a: *He was identified using **the statement** the boy gave*
>    2b: *He was identified using **a statement** the boy gave*
>    2c: *He was identified using **statements** the boy gave*

Pedants might argue that 1b/2b imply she gave *other* information/statements that weren't used in the identification process (or that ***the*** information/statement refers to something previously mentioned), but in my opinion that's, well, *pedantic*. The plural usage in 2c is relatively uncommon simply because in the real world the boy probably didn't give multiple statements (even if he *did*, perhaps only one aided the identification).

In short, for OP's exact context there's no significant *semantic* aspect to the inclusion of the article. Idiomatically we tend not to in any case, but it's not a *very* strong preference, and any apparent "deviation from the norm" would be even less likely to be noticed if there weren't another article following...

> 3: *He was identified using **the** information **little Johnny** gave*

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer, FumbleFingers! I've taken the liberty of adding the screenshot to your post; I hope you don't mind. Google Chrome's "Lightshot" extension works like a charm.

Comment: @CopperKettle: Ta muchly! I've duly added "Lightshot" to my browser ready for next time!

Answer (score 7):

The original sentence is perfectly correct.  You can, however, write it as "the information" without changing the meaning substantially.  The choice to include 'the' or not is a question of style.

Comment: Sure, it's a question of style, but the use or non-use of the article do differ the meaning.

Comment: @GoDucks In what way?

Comment: Well to answer your question @Kevin would basically require me to write an anwer to the original question asked on this page :) ...and that is something I am not sure I can do at this time. Basically, anytime you use a [determinative in English](http://www.linguisticsgirl.com/linguistic-definition-of-determinative/) you are adding some, uh, information to the meaning. Here *the information* differs from *information* because it refers to definite information rather than fuzzy-wuzzy indefinite information. I can't go further than that in a comment.

Comment: Then post an answer?

Answer (score 4):

If there is a quote of the child before the sentence in your question, i.e. "We live 1.8 miles away." or "Our house is 1.8 miles north from here" before the sentence in your question,  the definite article should be used.

In the article, we can never know what exactly the child said to the police. We could only assume that it might have been related with the location of his/her house.

> Police and the emergency services were able to find out where Kevin
>   Djene's father lived from **(some)** information the child provided.

The child could have given a few pieces of information and that's all we can know for sure from the context. Therefore, the **the** is not required and we could determine that the determiner **some** is elided in the sentence.

If you contrast "Pass me (some) information that the suspect has provided." with "Pass me the information that the suspect has provided," it is clear that the use of the definite article is context-dependent.

Answer (score 1):

"**The** information" in this case refers to the collective data given to the police from the witness, rather than information gathered as a whole. It's commonly used as we are speaking definitively about a specific segment of a uncountable noun.

For instance, **data** is a uncountable noun, but when reporting on scientific studies we would always refer to *the data*, as we refer solely to the data collected for the study.